# Filter Array on same name and date

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var Array = [{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-23"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-22"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-18"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-19"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-10-12"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-06-12"}]
```

What would be the best way to filter the above array on the following condition.

*If the name is the same, then filter away all the objects with the same name and leave only the object with the latest date left.

All I can think of is to do for loops. Note that Date is a real dateObject and not a string as I have wrote above which means that you can do Date comparisons.

Comment: IMHO there is no reasonable way to do so in JS except looping (`for` or `forEach`).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.reduce()`, i was able to get it down to an object containing only Temp and Temp2 with their dates:

```
var obj = array.reduce(function(base,cur){
    if (base[cur.Name]) {
        if (base[cur.Name].Date < cur.Date) {
            base[cur.Name].Date = cur.Date;
        } else {
            return base;
        }
    } else {
        base[cur.Name] = cur;
        return base;
    }
},{});
```

From there, you can just get the object's values with `Object.keys().map()`:

```
array = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k){
    return obj[k];
});
```

Comment: Will this work if the order of objects in the array is random?

Comment: I didn't test, but it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var Array = [{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-23"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-22"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-18"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-19"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-10-12"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-06-12"}]

var result = {};
Array.forEach(function(item) {
  var name = item['Name'];
  if(result[name]) {
    result[name].push(item['Date']);
  } else {
    result[name] = [item['Date']];
  }
})
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(item) {
  result[item] = Math.max.apply(null, result[item]);
})
```

aggragate the array by name to `{Name: 'Temp', Date: ['2014-10-23', '2013-10-32', 'xxxx']}`
then get the max date by Math.max.apply

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [{"Name":"Temp","Date":new Date("2014-10-23")},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":new Date("2014-10-22")},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":new Date("2014-10-18")},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":new Date("2014-10-19")},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":new Date("2014-10-12")},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":new Date("2014-06-12")}];

var obj = {};
for(var i in array){
    if(!obj[array[i].Name] || obj[array[i].Name].getTime() < array[i].Date.getTime())
        obj[array[i].Name] = array[i].Date;
}
```

then if you need it to be an array of objects:

```
array = [];
for(var name in obj){
    array.push({Name: name, Date: obj[name]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Works perfect for any random orders

```
var Array = [{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-03"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-22"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-18"},
{"Name":"Temp","Date":"2014-10-19"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-10-12"},
{"Name":"Temp2","Date":"2014-06-12"}];

var tempArray = []; //This array will hold your Result Set

var tempArrayName = [];

var tempDate = {};

$.each(Array, function(i, v) {

  if(tempArrayName.indexOf(Array[i].Name) < 0){
    tempArray.push({ "Name":Array[i].Name,"Date":Array[i].Date});
    tempArrayName.push(Array[i].Name);
    tempDate[Array[i].Name] = Array[i].Date;
  }else{
   if( new Date((Array[i].Date))> new Date(tempDate[Array[i].Name])){

      $.each(tempArray, function(j, k) {
        if(tempArray[j].Name == Array[i].Name){
          tempArray[j].Date = Array[i].Date;
        }
      });
    }   
  }

});


console.log(tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against overwriting the Array object. Anyhow,
one way would be to group the dates using an object:

```
var data = [
    {"Name":"Temp","Date": new Date("2014-10-23")},
    {"Name":"Temp","Date": new Date("2014-10-22")},
    {"Name":"Temp","Date": new Date("2014-10-18")},
    {"Name":"Temp","Date": new Date("2014-10-19")},
    {"Name":"Temp2","Date": new Date("2014-10-12")},
    {"Name":"Temp2","Date": new Date("2014-06-12")}
];

var name2dates = Object.create(null);
data.forEach(function(thing){
    if(!name2dates[thing.Name]){
        name2dates[thing.Name] = thing.Date;
    }else{
        name2dates[thing.Name] = thing.Date > name2dates[thing.Name] ?
            thing.Date : name2dates[thing.Name];
    }
});
```

And to create a 'filtered' array from this, if that's what you
need, then:

```
Object.keys(name2dates).map(function(name){
    return {Name: name, Date: name2dates[name]};
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this helpful?

```
$.grep(Array, function(v) {
        return v.Name === "Temp";
    }).reduce(function (a, b) { return a.Date > b.Date ? a : b; });
```